# jQWidgets datatable and columns on demand

Tags: jquery, jqwidget

I am building POC module on jqxdatatable where user will have flexibility to add/remove optional columns.
Let me elaborate in details, For example following is my table initially loads with default 6 columns.I would like to give an option with 2 more columns Department and country with check-box so if user wants to add any of these two optional columns they can just select/deselect the check-box and that column will appear/disappear on the grid.

[image]

Please note I would prefer to have XML data source.

Is it possible with jqxdatatable ?

Answer (score 0):

jQWidgets Team just confirmed it's not possible :( . I would love to hear if someone could suggest same can be achieved by any other JS library.

http://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/jqwidgets-datatable-and-columns-on-demand/